# .net core unit test project failing to build in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, build-pipeline

In my solution I have project targetting .netstandard 2.0, as we cannot have test case project targeting the same platform, I am using .netcore 3.1 unit test project, even after I updated the build pipeline to use .net 3.1, I am facing below issue at restore nuget step in build pipeline.

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\a\1\s\src\SampleProject\test\UnitTest\UnitTest.csproj])
##[error]Packages failed to restore
```

Note : https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AzureDevOpsContinuousBuildDeployTestWithASPNETCore22PreviewInOneHour.aspx
is the link I followed to troubleshoot this issue but still facing the same error.

Comment: _The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1_ message tells you, that you should update the SDK on your build agent

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Agree! Any link mentioning the steps for same?

Comment: I'm on windows-2022 image. For some unexplainable reason, unit test project won't build or at least no produce a DLL to run later.

Comment: I found this solution to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971457/1548275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from the error that you were running the pipeline on agent vs2017-win2016.  In agent vs2017-win2016 the older version msbuild in vs2017 is invoked while executing nuget restore command.

I have encountered a simmilar issue, and it seems that the older version msbuild cannot find the installed .NET Core 3.1 correctly.

Please have a try using agent `windows-2019` (windows-latest) to run your pipeline. And use task [Use .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops)
 to install  .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and one thing I would like to add is always use latest nuget version while restoring it.